# Issue with app.yaml porting an existing webapp on google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, debugging, porting, app.yaml

I'm a PHP newbie and I'm trying to port a webapp which is already working on the Google App Engine.
I read the GAE docs about the configuration file which I need to write ( app.yaml)

Now I reached the point where the launcher is serving the app but the "PHP flow" reach a page totally blank instead of a window with some data and a form that I'm expecting.

In which way I can debug that PHP flow too see what is appening wrong?

In detail these are the files which run wrongly:

index.php in root dir:

```
<?php
    include_once('tao/install/init.php');
    if(!tao_install_utils_System::isTAOInstalled()){
    header("location:tao/install");
}
else{
    header("location:tao/Main/entry");
}
?>
```

So the file init.php in tao/install will be called the first run of the app

```
<?php 
// -- Install bootstrap
$rootDir = dir(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../');
$root = realpath($rootDir->path) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;
define('TAO_INSTALL_PATH', $root);
define('GENERIS_PATH', $root.'generis/');
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $root. PATH_SEPARATOR . GENERIS_PATH);


function install_loader($class_name){
    foreach (array(TAO_INSTALL_PATH, GENERIS_PATH) as $dir) {
        $path = str_replace('_', '/', $class_name);
        $file =  'class.' . basename($path). '.php';
        $filePath = $dir . dirname($path) . '/' . $file;
        if (file_exists($filePath)){
            require_once  $filePath;
            break;
        }
        else{
            $file = 'interface.' . basename($path). '.php';
            $filePath = $dir . dirname($path) . '/' . $file;
            if (file_exists($filePath)){
                require_once $filePath;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('install_loader');

common_log_Dispatcher::singleton()->init(array(
    array(
        'class'         => 'SingleFileAppender',
        'threshold'     => common_Logger::TRACE_LEVEL,
        'file'          => TAO_INSTALL_PATH.'tao/install/log/install.log',
)));
require_once (GENERIS_PATH.'vendor/autoload.php');
require_once ('tao/helpers/class.Display.php');
require_once ('tao/helpers/class.Uri.php');

?>
```

And this is my temporary app.yaml

```
application: myapp
version: alpha-001
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /tao/install
  script: /tao/install/init.php

#- url: /stylesheets
#  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

**EDIT**

I think I need to edit the app.yaml for :

```
require_once (GENERIS_PATH.'vendor/autoload.php');
require_once ('tao/helpers/class.Display.php');
require_once ('tao/helpers/class.Uri.php');
```

But I don't understood how

**SECOND EDIT**

That's the log of GAE launcher

```
2015-03-31 15:59:05 Running command: "['G:\\Python27\\python.exe', 'H:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=15080', '--admin_port=8007', u'F:\\davide\\tesi\\taov1']"
INFO     2015-03-31 15:59:07,522 devappserver2.py:726] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-03-31 15:59:07,611 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:63287
INFO     2015-03-31 15:59:07,617 dispatcher.py:186] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:15080
INFO     2015-03-31 15:59:07,618 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8007
INFO     2015-03-31 16:09:54,970 module.py:737] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-03-31 16:09:55,045 module.py:737] default: "GET /tao/install HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2015-03-31 16:09:55,207 module.py:737] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: If `include_once('tao/install/init.php');` is the correct location then you have to change your yaml file like this `- url: /tao/install
  script: tao/install/init.php` I believe `toa` dir is inside the root

Comment: Thanks for the interest.

Yes, tao is a dir inside the root but if I use :
- url: /tao/install script: tao/install/init.php
instead of
- url: /tao/install script: /tao/install/init.php

I get the same situation

Comment: Can you deploy it to non default version and check the logs in there?

Comment: I dont know even what is a non default version, where can I read about it?
I found something about on google docs for gae but not in the PHP section

Comment: You can check [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld) out! you can change `version: alpha-001` to `version: alpha-test` in your app.yaml file and deploy. Then go to your app engine application -- version and click on `alpha-test` hyper link, then go back to logs select `alpha-test` and see what's happening

Comment: @SasiVarunan I've tryed to deploy it on GAE but I cant cause there are too many files for my profile (Error 400: Max number of files and blobs is 10000. )

Comment: please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913734/hitting-max-number-of-files-and-blobs-for-google-app-engine) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165753/google-application-engine-maximum-number-of-static-files)

Comment: @SasiVarunan, thanks I really appreciate your interest.

I've edited the log in the answer, I got it from the tool GAE launcher used to deploy app locally.
I think the problem is with these three required_once(xxx) don't implemented in app.yaml.

Comment: require_once won't work in app.yaml. Read  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig for more info on the syntax. Based on your log in "SECOND EDIT", the PHP scripts that handles /tao/install returnd HTTP 200, which it executed without error. Put some echo statements in that script to debug further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally have found the answer. The problem was app.yaml as @Mars said me.
This is the correct form:

```
application: mytaov1
version: alpha-test
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /
script: index.php
- url: /tao/install
script: /tao/install/index.html
```

The include() path was not necessary in the app.yaml like the required() path.
They were called and handled without problem.